# Matlab: how to integrate over subset of input variables of a function while fixing the value of the other variables?

Tags: matlab

suppose I want to integrate a function of the form output=myfunc(x,y,var1,var2,...,varN) with respect to just the x and y variable, over the region of x for x0 to x1, and y from fy0(x) to fy1(x), where fy0() and fy1() are two function of x. The other variables of myfunc() - var1, var2, ..., varN will take some fixed value each time I do the 2d integral.

btw: myfunc() is rather long and can't be written as an anonymous function with @.

how can I do it? many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, fix all the constants to get a 2-parameter function:

```
var1=3
var2=pi
myfunc2=@(x,y)myfunc(x,y,var1,var2)
```

This way `myfunc2` is a anonymous function which calls `myfunc` with the given x and y and the defined values for `var1` amd `var2`. Keep in mind that `myfunc2` copies the variables to it's own scope. If you modify `var1` and `var2` after creating the anonymous function it won't modify `myfunc2`.

Now you can use `integral2`. For ymin and ymax function handles are accepted.